# LINQ query Where ID does not exist as a property in a list of objects

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a list of objects that contain ID numbers. I want to query a table in my database to give me all the rows where the ID *do not* match the ID of any of the objects in my list.

```
List<Item> allItems = new List<Item>();
// Populate allItems
```

An `Item` is a simple object with a `public int ItemID` and `public string Name`.

Here is the LINQ I have tried to query a particular table to give me only the rows that do not exist as an `ItemID` in `allItems`:

```
var filtered = ctx.PurchasedItems.Where(x => allItems.Select(y => y.ItemID).ToList().Contains(x.FK_ItemID)).ToList();
```

As you can see, `dbo.PurchasedItems` has a column `FK_ItemID` that matches up to the `ItemID` in the object Item.

Although this compiles, I get the following error when I run:

> "Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'DemoProject.Models.ItemDatabase.PurchasedItems'. Only primitive types
>   or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Another method I tried was:

```
var p = ctx.PurchasedItems.Where(x => x.FK_ItemID.IsAnyOf(allItems.Select(y => y.ItemID).ToArray())).ToList();
```

...but this produced a similar error.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Not sure, maybe to select (y => y.ItemID  == System.DBNull)

Comment: It is more efficient to do it in two queries : var items = allItems.Select(x => x.ItemID).ToList();
var filtered = ctx.PurchasedItems.Where(x => items.Contains(x.FK_ItemID)).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng It's not that it's more efficient, it's that EF cannot deal with a collection of non primitive types because it's trying to translate that into SQL.

Comment: The following will work bu tis less efficient : var filtered = ctx.PurchasedItems.Where(x => allItems.Select(x => x.ItemID).Contains(x.FK_ItemID)).ToList();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will rewrite the question

> I have a list (`someItems`) of objects with numeric IDs. I want to query a table `PurchasedItems` in my database to give me all the rows where the `FK_ItemID` *do not* match the ID of any of the objects in my list `someItems`.

My answer:

```
List<Item> someItems = new List<Item>();
// Populate someItems
List<int> someItemIDs = someItems.Select(i=>i.ID).ToList();
var filtered = ctx.PurchasedItems
                  .Where(x => !someItemIDs.Contains(x.FK_ItemID))
                  .ToList();
```

As pointed out by @juharr 's comment, EF cannot deal with a collection of non primitive types because it's trying to translate that into SQL. You can create the collection `someItemIDs` first.

Comment: Thanks. This was actually the solution I was using elsewhere - 2 separate queries - but I thought it was a bit of a cheat and that there was a way to get my attempted queries to work. Thanks for clarifying.